# path type variable in Flask API endpoint is splitting the variable value

Tags: python, flask

I have an endpoint in my API like below:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/price/<path:url>/')
def Ex(url):
    return {'urlwas':url}

app.run()
```

The problem is that when I call the API with this `http://127.0.0.1:5000/price/https://puresourceindia.in/store/index.php/?route=product/product&product_id=479`

it should return this `{"urlwas":"https://puresourceindia.in/store/index.php/?route=product/product&product_id=479"}`

but it returns `{"urlwas":"https://puresourceindia.in/store/index.php"}`

I am unable to understand what is happening here, and how to tackle this situation?

Comment: Try this `@app.route('/price/<string:url>/')`. Maybe it the type path doesn't interpret named parameter in url as part of url and does , thus returns the url before `?`

Comment: @charchit If is use string `<string:url>` it will not accept splash `/`. I want to slash `/` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to URL encode the parameter, the call should become:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/price/https%3A%2F%2Fpuresourceindia.in%2Fstore%2Findex.php%2F%3Froute%3Dproduct%2Fproduct%26product_id%3D479
```

and the result then becomes the one expected:

```
{"urlwas":"https://puresourceindia.in/store/index.php/?route=product/product&product_id=479"}
```

See here how to URL encode your string: https://www.urlencoder.org/